# How to install specific version of Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

I install the latest version of Kubernetes with the following command on Raspberry PI 3 running Raspbian Stretch.

```
$ curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add - && \
  echo "deb http://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list && \
  sudo apt-get update -q && \
  sudo apt-get install -qy kubeadm
```

Currently this will install v1.10.0.

How can I install a specific version of Kubernetes? Let's say v1.9.6.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

To install specific version of the package it is enough to define it during the `apt-get install` command:

```
apt-get install -qy kubeadm=<version>
```

But in the current case `kubectl` and `kubelet` packages are installed by dependencies when we install `kubeadm`, so all these three packages should be installed with a specific version:

```
$ curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add - && \
  echo "deb http://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list && \
  sudo apt-get update -q && \
  sudo apt-get install -qy kubelet=<version> kubectl=<version> kubeadm=<version>
```

where available `<version>` is:

```
curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/dists/kubernetes-xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages | grep Version | awk '{print $2}'
```

For your particular case it is:

```
$ curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add - && \
  echo "deb http://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list && \
  sudo apt-get update -q && \
  sudo apt-get install -qy kubelet=1.9.6-00 kubectl=1.9.6-00 kubeadm=1.9.6-00
```

Comment: Since late march 2019, for version of kubernetes 1.13 and earlier this no longer works. A error message `The following packages have unmet dependencies: kubeadm : Depends: kubernetes-cni (= 0.6.0) but 0.7.5-00 is to be installed` is displayed. More [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/75701).

Comment: the issue I had was I put the version as 1.19.0 while it should be 1.19.0-00 the "-00" is the fix

Comment: I tried this on MacOS Monterey and got this when I tried running kubectl: `fatal error: runtime: bsdthread_register error`

Comment: Really helpful!

Answer (score 21):

None of the answers get small tip about where get proper package version.
So my solution for debian 10 (buster) how to install not latest (1.20) but 1.18 version of kubeadm

```sh
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y apt-transport-https curl

curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add -

cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list
deb https://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main
EOF

apt update
```

There is the most important thing I got a problem :). Get available package versions

```
apt list -a kubeadm
```

From the output select which you want to install

```
# apt list -a kubeadm
Listing... Done
kubeadm/kubernetes-xenial 1.20.0-00 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.18.13-00]
kubeadm/kubernetes-xenial 1.19.5-00 amd64
kubeadm/kubernetes-xenial 1.19.4-00 amd64
kubeadm/kubernetes-xenial 1.19.3-00 amd64
kubeadm/kubernetes-xenial 1.19.2-00 amd64
kubeadm/kubernetes-xenial 1.19.1-00 amd64
kubeadm/kubernetes-xenial 1.19.0-00 amd64
kubeadm/kubernetes-xenial,now 1.18.13-00 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 1.20.0-00]
kubeadm/kubernetes-xenial 1.18.12-00 amd64
kubeadm/kubernetes-xenial 1.18.10-00 amd64
```

For me it was latest version for 1.18: **1.18.13-00**
And now simply specify this version for packages

```sh
apt install -y kubeadm=1.18.13-00 kubelet=1.18.13-00 kubectl=1.18.13-00
```

Hope it could save somebody time and nervous

Answer (score 10):

on Mac  to install v1.8.5 of kubernetes follow the below steps

## Get the kubectl binary.

```
curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.8.5/bin/darwin/amd64/kubectl
```

## Make the kubectl binary executable.

```
chmod +x ./kubectl
```

## Move the kubectl executable to /usr/local/bin.

```
sudo mv ./kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl
```

Comment: This does not install kubernetes. This just downloads `kubectl` and makes it executable.

Answer (score 5):

You can  use below command  to install Particular version of Kubernetes In Centos/Redhat Machines and same format can use other distributions as well .

**yum install -y kubelet-1.11.1 kubeadm-1.11.1 kubectl-1.11.1 kubernetes-cni-0.6.0-0.x86_64**