# How to install Hasura Platform on custom VPS?

Tags: kubernetes, vps, hasura

I want to try Hasura Platform for small project.
I have a limitation on the geographical location of the server, so Digital Ocean is not suitable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install Kubernetes on a VPS (say running Ubuntu) using [kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/install-kubeadm/) and then setup Hasura on that Kubernetes Cluster by following the guide [here](https://docs.platform.hasura.io/0.15/platform/manual/install-hasura/general.html).

A sample `custom-cluster.yaml` might look like this:

```
name: '<cluster-name>'
alias: '<cluster-alias>'
kubeContext: '<kube-context>'
config:
  namespace: hasura
  configmap: controller-conf
infra:
  provider: custom
metadata:
  namespaces:
    hasura: hasura
    user: default
  gateway:
    ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 80
    - name: https
      port: 443
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 443
    - name: ssh
      port: 2022
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 22
    selector:
      app: gateway
    externalIPs: ["<your-vps-public-ip>"]
  postgres:
    volume:
      hostPath:
        path: '/data/hasura-data'
      name: postgres-pv
  filestore:
    volume:
      hostPath:
        path: '/data/hasura-data'
      name: filestore-pv
  sessionStore:
    volume:
      hostPath:
        path: '/data/hasura-data'
      name: redis-pv
```

Answer (score 3):

### Implementation of @Shahidh's answer

*to VPS 1 Core, 2 Gb, Ubuntu 16.04 x86_64*

[discussion on Discord](https://discordapp.com/channels/407792526867693568/408207976499904513/499525490852495370)

#### VPS:

```
ssh root@<your-vps-public-ip>
```

Install Docker:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install -qy docker.io
```

Install Kubernetes *(was tested on v1.10)*

- install kubeadm

  - https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/install-kubeadm/
  - https://stackoverflow.com/a/49722179/1515449
- available versions: `curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/dists/kubernetes-xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages | grep Version | awk '{print $2}'`

:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-transport-https curl

curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key add -

cat <<EOF >/etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list
deb https://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main
EOF

apt-get update
apt-get install -qy kubelet=1.10.11-00 kubeadm=1.10.11-00 kubectl=1.10.11-00
apt-mark hold kubelet kubeadm kubectl

kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16 \
--apiserver-advertise-address=<your-vps-public-ip> \
--kubernetes-version=1.10.11

export KUBECONFIG=/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf

kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/bc79dd1505b0c8681ece4de4c0d86c5cd2643275/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml

kubectl taint nodes --all node-role.kubernetes.io/master-

mkdir -p /data/hasura-data
```

Check: `kubectl get all --namespace=kube-system`

#### On local machine:

```
 mkdir ~/k8s/
 scp root@<you-vps-public-ip>:/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf ~/k8s/
```

set Kubernetes context:

```
 export KUBECONFIG=~/k8s/admin.conf
```

check:

```
kubectl get nodes
```

get `<kube-context>` for custom-cluster.yaml:

```
 kubectl config current-context
```

install hasura cluster:

```
 cd <project-directory>
 hasura cluster install \
 --file custom-cluster.yaml \
 --domain=<your-vps-public-ip>.xip.io
```

add cluster to project:

```
hasura cluster add --file custom-cluster.yaml
```

Comment: hasura cluster install gives the following error "Installing Hasura failed error=[1024] key 'hasuraID' not found in config.json", any idea? Thx!

Comment: @Diego call `hasura login` first.

Comment: Don't forget to apply config:
`hasura platform:conf apply`