# I want to install kubernet 1.15 on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: kubernetes

I want to install kubernetes v1.15 on ubuntu 18.04 but every time i run the following command :

```
apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-transport-https curl

curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add

sudo apt-add-repository "deb http://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main"

sudo apt-get install -qy kubelet=1.13.0-00 kubectl=1.13.0-00 kubeadm=1.13.0-00
```

It downloaded only the current version ....can anyone help ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install specific version of Kubernetes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49721708/how-to-install-specific-version-of-kubernetes)

Answer (score 1):

I successfully installed version 1.15 using those commands:

**Get the Kubernetes gpg key:**

```
curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

**Add the Kubernetes repository:**

```
cat << EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list
deb https://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main
EOF
```

**Update your packages:**

```
sudo apt-get update
```

**And then install kubelet, kubeadm, and kubectl:**

```
sudo apt-get install -y  kubelet=1.15.0-00 kubeadm=1.15.0-00 kubectl=1.15.0-00
```

**You will also want to hold them to prevent unwanted updates:**

```
sudo apt-mark hold docker-ce kubelet kubeadm kubectl
```

Can you try using those commands and let me know if its works?

Comment: While run the command :

sudo apt-get install -y  kubelet=1.15.0-00 kubeadm=1.15.0-00 kubectl=1.15.0-0

getting the following error :

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '1.15.0-0' for 'kubectl' was not found

Comment: There was one 0 missing from the command. It should be kubectl=1.15.0-00 instead of kubectl=1.15.0-0. I have corrected the answer as well. Can try now?