# Kubectl server version is not upgrading

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I'm facing an issue with kubectl server version.

> Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"20",
> GitVersion:"v1.20.4",
> GitCommit:"e87da0bd6e03ec3fea7933c4b5263d151aafd07c",
> GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-02-18T16:12:00Z",
> GoVersion:"go1.15.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"} Server
> Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"18", GitVersion:"v1.18.8",
> GitCommit:"9f2892aab98fe339f3bd70e3c470144299398ace",
> GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-08-13T16:04:18Z",
> GoVersion:"go1.13.15", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

So, when I try to join a new node I get this:

> root@osswrkprbe007:~# kubeadm join 192.168.14.149:6443 --token
> 2w06dl.jz1clwuvknkbabqp     --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash
> sha256:00370f52b8b14ae094ae83cb8333b9c7a141df9de7b039aeb33399ef5547f36f
> [preflight] Running pre-flight checks     [WARNING IsDockerSystemdCheck]:
> detected "cgroupfs" as the Docker cgroup driver. The recommended
> driver is "systemd". Please follow the guide at
> https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/cri/ [preflight] Reading
> configuration from the cluster... [preflight] FYI: You can look at
> this config file with 'kubectl -n kube-system get cm kubeadm-config -o
> yaml' error execution phase preflight: unable to fetch the
> kubeadm-config ConfigMap: this version of kubeadm only supports
> deploying clusters with the control plane version >= 1.19.0. Current
> version: v1.18.8 To see the stack trace of this error execute with
> --v=5 or higher

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is not in the [kubectl](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl) version, problem in [kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/) version.

- Your kubectl is 1.20.4
- Your cluster is 1.18.8
- your kubeadm most probably 1.19 and it sais you "**this version of kubeadm only supports deploying clusters with the control plane version >= 1.19.0.**"

So use lower and appropriate kubeadm version(e.g 1.18.8) - it will help.

Refer to this answer to check [how to install specific version of Kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49722179/9929015).